# How can I get each filename printed to the output with pattern matched results

Tags: python, bash, unix

```
  while read line
  do
  awk '
     /ERROR/ {
            print
            for (i=1; i<=10; i++) {
                   getline; print
            }
            exit
            }
 ' $line  
   echo $line    
   done < logfiles.csv >> results.csv
```

with the above code I am getting output like below in my results.csv file

```
  1.log 
  ERROR
  2.log
  ERROR
```

but wanted the output like below

```
  1.log ERROR
  2.log ERROR
```

my logfile.csv contains information like below

```
1.log
2.log
```

Comment: Could you format your question so that the code is properly visible? See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: @PrathimaPuttagunta : Also show a relevant excerpt of the logfile. As your posting stands now, I can not see where you print the `1.log`.

Comment: Why is this tagged *python*? Are you looking for a Python way?

Comment: either shell or python will do..Thanks

Comment: @user1934428 i added echo statement      awk '
     /ERROR/ {
            print
            for (i=1; i<=10; i++) {
                   getline; print
            }
            exit
            }
 ' $line  
   echo $line

Comment: have you tried this? grep --with-filename '<pattern>' <file>

Comment: @Ashkan after matching pattren i need to print next 10 lines and there were lot of error files in logfiles.csv file .. so the command should iterate through whole logfiles.csv and match the pattren

Comment: you could add the option to print the next 10 lines after the match 

grep -A 10 --with-filename '<pattern>' <file>

grep will look through your file and show all occurences and also 10 lines after the match. If you need to see anything before the match then you can use -B option

Comment: Also what do you mean that there are many error files in logfiles.csv? Does this logfiles.csv contain filepaths?

Comment: Please update your examples. Your script uses an input file `logfiles.csv` and get triggered by lines with `ERROR`, your example input has the name `logfile.csv` without an `ERROR` pattern and the wanted output doesn't show the next 10 lines from input that should be shown.
We want to help, not score on a quiz who can guess the requirements best.

Comment: it is searching for a pattern ["ERROR"] and if it found the pattern it print next 10 lines after the matched pattern. eg:  **logfile.csv**      contains file names like [1.log],[2.log] and so on.. if **1.log** contains ERROR it will print filename and the error description which is 10 lines below *ERROR*

Comment: @PrathimaPuttagunta : Then update your posting, to reflect the `echo` statement. It doesn't make sense to discuss the output of the script, when the script you are posting is not exactly the one which produced the output that you have posted.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I assume that:

- logfiles.csv is a text file that contains names of log files, one name per line
- each of those log file can contain the `ERROR` pattern, if it does, a line must be printed with the filename and `"ERROR"`
- the result must be in the file result.csv

It can be straighforward in Python:

```
with open("logfiles.csv") as files, open("result.csv", "w") as fdout:
    for filename in files:             # read input file line by line
        filename = filename.strip()    # strip end of line
        with open(filename) as fd:     # open each log file
            for line in fd:
                if 'ERROR' in line:    # search the pattern ERROR in any line
                    print(filename, 'ERROR', file=fdout) # message if found
                    break                                # and stop processing that log
```

Comment: your assumption is almost perfect.. I wanted to print 10 lines after the matched pattern.. Thank you for the reply